# Pandas Data data frame filtering after using pivot function

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please help me with my current error or suggest another way of doing this ?
Thanks a lot in advance

I have bellow data frame given bellow :-

```
GroupName  Id     Type1     Type2      Type 3
ABC         1       100       0            0
            2         0      -100          0 
            3         0       100         100
DEF         4       100       0            0 
            5        0        100          0
```

I want to filter the data frame such that it returns me all the rows and the GroupName where one or more of the columns (Type1 /Type2/Type3) has +ve and a -ve value .

OUTPUT in the above df it will return be only

```
GroupName  Id     Type1     Type2      Type 3
ABC         1       100       0            0
            2         0      **-100**          0 
            3         0       100         **100**
```

I tried

```
df[df.gt(0).any(axis=1) & df.lt(0).any(axis=1)]
```

getting error

```
    if level_codes[key] == -1:
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I created this df by using a pivot table

```
df= old_df.pivot_table(index=["GroupName","Id"], columns="Type", values="Value",
                                              aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.  With the provided data, I get an empty dataframe, which makes sense.

Comment: I think OP is targeting first index level `ABC` since it has both pos and neg values. `DEF` doesn't have neg.

Comment: Oh, for the whole segment.  Ok, that could work.

Comment: yes Quang Hoang is right

Comment: @QuangHoang is my answer capture what you were thinking?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,i didn't explain it properly .. what I am looking for is  not change the value of  **-100** to -100 . The ** was typo I was trying to make it BOLD   I want to filter the data frame such that it returns me all the rows and the GroupName where one or more of the columns (Type1 /Type2/Type3) has +ve and a -ve value .  So that I get only Group Type ABC and all its Id rows as that group has a +ve and -ve value . I dont get Group Type DEF and all its ID rows as that group has only +ve values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def posandneg(d):
    return np.in1d([1, -1], np.sign(d)).all()

df.groupby(level=0).filter(posandneg)

             Type1 Type2 Type 3
GroupName Id                   
ABC       1    100     0      0
          2      0  -100      0
          3      0   100    100
​
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,i didn't explain it properly .. what I am looking for is not change the value of -100 to -100 . The ** was typo I was trying to make it BOLD I want to filter the data frame such that it returns me all the rows and the GroupName where one or more of the columns (Type1 /Type2/Type3) has +ve and a -ve value . So that I get only Group Type ABC and all its Id rows as that group has a +ve and -ve value . I dont get Group Type DEF and all its ID rows as that group has only +ve values

Comment: I think I understand that now.  And I believe that is exactly what I've provided.  Notice that only `GroupName` equal to `'ABC'` was returned.

Comment: hmm it is returning me the same data frame

Comment: run `df.head().to_dict()` and update your question with the result OR reply to this comment with the results.

Comment: sorry proprietary data don't want to get into trouble by sharing it here . Let me see if I can understand your logic . You are picking up each GroupName and passing it to  posandneg(d) then confused by this line return np.in1d([1, -1], np.sign(d)).all() . Doesn't in1d check two array values are equal or not and then return True\False . The value can be any +ve number or -ve number in any of the columns .You are using [1,-1]. Apologies if I am missing something . Still learning python

Comment: `in1d` returns `True` or `False` for each element of the first array (`[-1, 1]`) depending on if `-1` or `1` is in the second array.  If both `-1` and `1` are in the second array, it'll return `[True, True]`.  I check that with `all`.  So the final thing returns `True` only if both `-1` and `1` are in the second array.  Ok, so what is the second array.  I use `np.sign` which returns an array of equal size with `-1`, `0`, and `1` depending if elements are negative, zero, or positive.  Hopefully, that clears some things up.

Comment: This definitely clears quite a bit and thanks a lot for detailed explanation. My question is regarding  first array [-1, 1] . You are checking for only +1 and -1 values in second array . But second array can have any +ve or -ve values like + 600, -783432. Then I will miss those numbers right . I guess that is why same data set is getting returned for me as my second  second array doesn't contain any [-1, 1] but values like + 600 ,-78432 . Basically what I am trying to say the values are not fixed hence I wont be able to hardcode it in first array. Hope this make sense to you

Comment: The function `np.sign` turns all negative values to `-1` and all positive values to `1`.  So data like `[-600, 100000, -0.5, 0.0000002, 0, 0]` will get turned into `[-1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0]` and thus I only have to look for `-1` and `1` to determine if there are positive values and negative values.

Comment: Thanks a lot make sense